# how to trigger a event in angular when the browser is closed not refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

how to delete token in local storage only on browser close not on refresh I am using below approach but it is getting removed on refresh also please provide a better solution
as I tried many ways it is getting failed all times

> is there any alternate way
>   please provide a solution thanks in advance

```
window.onunload = function () {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
}
```

Comment: `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: @PankajParkar I think `onbeforeunload` is triggered when the page is refreshed too.

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659544/9692290 it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with the onunload event, but you can try to store your token in localSession instead of localStorage

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's **impossible to tell the difference**.

From the web page's point of view, closing the tab/browser and re-opening it again, and refreshing the page are the exact same actions. There's no reason for it to be different.